# How can I install Firebird on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I can’t find a good method to install Firebird ver. 2.5 or ver. 3.0.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5)

Firebird stable [2.5.x](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/) is located into [this](https://launchpad.net/~mapopa/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) repository (ppa) for LTS and current supported [Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

The ppa repository must be added this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapopa
```

Then you need to update the cache repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Here is how you can inspect the firebird2.5 related packages

```
apt-cache search firebird2.5-*
```

Install the super server package (you will be asked about the SYSDBA password and what service to enable : Super Server, Classic or Super Classic )

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-super
The following extra packages will be installed:
  firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc firebird2.5-dev firebird2.5-server-common libfbclient2 libib-util
Suggested packages:
  libfbembed2.5 firebird2.5-examples firebird2.5-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firebird2.5-server-common firebird2.5-super
The following packages will be upgraded:
  firebird2.5-common firebird2.5-common-doc firebird2.5-dev libfbclient2 libib-util
5 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,442kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.3MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
```

Or install Classic or Super Classic if you have more than one cpu (dual core or SMP machine) and want [SMP support](https://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/qsg25-classic-or-super.html)

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-classic
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-superclassic
```

You need to configure the package after is installed

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-super
```

Install the examples and dev files

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-examples firebird2.5-dev
```

The employee.fdb archive will be under this dir /usr/share/doc/firebird2.1-examples/examples/empbuild/

```
cd /usr/share/doc/firebird2.5-examples/examples/empbuild/
sudo gunzip employee.fdb.gz
sudo chown firebird.firebird employee.fdb
sudo mv employee.fdb /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/
Connect to database using the isql-fb console


$ isql-fb
SQL> connect "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb " user 'SYSDBA' password 'SYSDBApassword';
```

**always use localhost: in front of db path when using classic or superclassic in 2.5 this way the lock files and the shared memory segment will be owned by the 'firebird' user.** Another alternative is to add yourself to firebird group

```
$ sudo adduser `id -un` firebird
```

Then connect to the db in superclassic or classic

```
$ isql-fb
SQL> connect "localhost:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb " user 'SYSDBA' password 'SYSDBApassword';
```

If all is ok then you will have the message with what database connected and what user and ready to use sql prompt

```
Database:  "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb ", User: SYSDBA
SQL>
```

Now you can check the server version and the tables

```
SQL> show tables;
       COUNTRY                                CUSTOMER
       DEPARTMENT                             EMPLOYEE
       EMPLOYEE_PROJECT                       JOB
       PROJECT                                PROJ_DEPT_BUDGET
       SALARY_HISTORY                         SALES

SQL> show version;
ISQL Version: LI-V2.5.0.* Firebird 2.5
Server version:
Firebird/linux Intel (access method), version "LI-V2.5.0.* Firebird 2.5"
Firebird/linux Intel (remote server), version "LI-V2.5.0.* Firebird 2.5/tcp (eeepc)/P11"
Firebird/linux Intel (remote interface), version "LI-V2.5.0.* Firebird 2.5 Release Candidate 2/tcp (eeepc)/P11"
on disk structure version 11.1
```

To create a new database

```
SQL> create database "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/first_database.fdb" user 'SYSDBA' password 'SYSDBAPASSWORD';
SQL> connect "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/first_database.fdb" user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
Commit current transaction (y/n)?y
Committing.
Database:  "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/first_database.fdb", User: SYSDBA
SQL>
```

If you want to create a simple table then insert 1-2 rows and select from it here is one example

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(20));
SQL> show tables;
       TEST
SQL> INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 'John');
SQL> INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2, 'Joe');
SQL> select * from test;

          ID NAME                 
============ ==================== 
           1 John                 
           2 Joe
```

To quit the isql-fb console type quit

```
SQL> quit
CON>;
```

For a good open source GUI admin tool you might check the flamerobin administration tool included in ubuntu repository can be installed by an simple

```
sudo apt-get install flamerobin
```

Then use it from the menu Applications->Programming-> [FlameRobin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FlameRobin)

To use firebird with php , you will need the php5 driver

```
sudo apt-get install php5-interbase libapache2-mod-php5
sudo php5enmod interbase
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Next if you need to install an php administration tool like Firebird Web Admin

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
git clone git://github.com/mariuz/firebirdwebadmin.git 
mv firebirdwebadmin /var/www/html/firebirdwebadmin
```

and load it in the browser http://localhost/firebirdwebadmin