# Installing firebird 2.5 on ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, database, add-apt-repository

I want to install firebird 2.5 server on ubuntu 18.10

I followed this [installing firebird 2.5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5), but got stuck in

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mapopa
```

it says error

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mapopa/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

so I followed to the [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/apt-secure.8.html#user%20configuration), but doesn't quite grasp what it tells me to solve the problem. There's a similar question to this, [How to installing Firebird on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945327/how-to-installing-firebird-on-ubuntu-16-04) but it's just the same as [installing firebird 2.5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5)

## Update

I have no reason using Ubuntu 18.10 for this use case. Previously I thought about using docker for the Firebird server, so maybe the newest version is just fine. But things don't work as expected: the docker image can't read the database (probably I miss implement something too). So I tried to use the Firebird Ubuntu versions, got stuck, and then I came up with this question

So I downgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine.

Comment: 'No Release File' means that the PPA is incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. The PPA maintainer has not created an 18.10 version.

Comment: @user535733 so I should downgrade to the previous version? I thought the message `Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.` implies that I can install it but it's currently disabled?

Comment: That's one option. There are lots of SQL-Server solutions for Ubuntu that DO work with 18.10 - that's another option. Maybe somebody else has packaged Firebird - that's yet another option. Looks like you can install FB 3.0 from tarball instead of package - that's an option.

Comment: @user535733 Yes there's a lot of SQL Server, but my current use case is to use the Firebird server. Perhaps I just downgrade the Ubuntu then,

Comment: @otong For me it seems that you do strange and wrong things. If you need to create real server for the production, then you should choose LTS version of Ubuntu. This will solve the FireBird problem as 14.04 and 16.04 LTS have [firebird-2.5 packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=firebird2.5&searchon=names). Currently there are [no PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) with FireBird 2.5 Also it is very likely that you can not compile 2.5 on Ubuntu 18.10 because of the newest dependencies...

Comment: @N0rbert right, sorry I doesn't know much about Ubuntu. I have blindly selected the newest Ubuntu version for my needs. Previously I thought about using docker for the Firebird server, so maybe the newest version is just fine. But things don't work as expected: the docker image can't read the database (probably I miss implement something too). So I tried to use the Ubuntu versions, got stuck, and then I came up with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your server reliable, stable and suitable for the production environment you should choose LTS version of Ubuntu.

This will solve the FireBird problem as 14.04 and 16.04 LTS [have firebird-2.5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=firebird2.5&searchon=names) packages.

Currently there are [no PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) with FireBird 2.5.

Also it is very likely that you can not compile 2.5 on Ubuntu 18.10 because of the newest dependencies..

So my advice is to switch to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and install FireBird 2.5 into it.